# What exactly is the function of と in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particles

彼の車は私と同じです。

Does it have something to do with comparing nouns?

If so, why would と follow 私?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grammar of 彼の日本語のレベルは私と同じくらいだ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25846/grammar-of-%e5%bd%bc%e3%81%ae%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e%e3%81%ae%e3%83%ac%e3%83%99%e3%83%ab%e3%81%af%e7%a7%81%e3%81%a8%e5%90%8c%e3%81%98%e3%81%8f%e3%82%89%e3%81%84%e3%81%a0)

Comment: Please see the last half of [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/57077/5010), too.